# Importing external document to SOAP message import not working?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, servicenow, cucm

I am trying to integrate Service Now and Cisco UC Manager. I have gotten the WSDL from CUCM, as mentioned in Cisco DevNet: Administrative XML (AXL) - How To. The files are attached below. I also set up a Service Now developer instance, and I try to load the SOAP message provided into Service Now without success.

So I follow the instruction given here:
Create a SOAP message from a WSDL that references an external XSD file. Works fine with the sample SOAP provided.

Then I proceed to copy paste the content of AXLAPI.wsdl into WSDL XML field. Click submit and works fine so far. The windows return to the list of SOAP messages with the newly created CUCM.
Click on CUCM to enter again and go to SOAP message Imports. Create a New one and enter the content of AXLSoap.xsd into the external documents field.

[SOAP Message Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfQRn.jpg)

Choose Submit. Then things get weird. A new page is loaded:

[A new SOAP Message Import page appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxS8v.jpg)

Now you may notice this page is EXACTLY the same as the previous one. So I tried to enter the details again and click Submit, then a blank page appears again and apparently the data I entered was not recorded and no message was imported.

Now what I think might be the problem is the input message is too long for Service Now to process, as if I truncate the above file then it is submitted and recorded (although it won't work because there are functions missing). So after trying around I ended up in some system definitions tables, with one called sys_soap_message_import, which is where records from SOAP Message Imports is supposed to end up in. There is a column called External Documents with the maximum length set to 75000 (I'm not sure of the unit). So I thought this might be the case and increased it to the maximum allowable length but after trying again the problem has not been solved.

Is there any workaround this? The documents I attach is around 3MB, 50000 lines and 3 million characters. I set the maximum length to 2 billion without any success.

What might be the problem and how can I solve it? Has anyone successfully integrated Service Now and CUCM?

add https:// to the below links

AXLSoap.xsd: ufile.io/wfb4n

AXLAPI.wsdl: ufiles.io/wo5z5

Comment: Is REST an option? It's much easier to work with.

Comment: REST doesn't work with CUCM sadly

Comment: have you checked the logs right after you import? you might get some insight.